# Can't change to Nvidia drivers Ubuntu18.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, 18.04

In the few days since this LTS release I've clean installed 3 times! The first time I thought I'd messed up the install when my screen kept frezing. The mouse cursor would still move but not work on anything. No key combinations would work either. Nvidia driver choice would always revert to nouveau.
The second time I tried the ppa of experimental nvidia drivers. Then aborted their installs with errors.
Now I'm on this 3rd install. It freezes when I'm in a browser or not. Seems to be random. And still when I try to change to nvidia drivers it just reverts to the default - nouveau

I never had any problems with 16.04 LTS but I'd like to be able to use this new version, it looks good, when it doesn't freeze on me!

I have Nvidia geforce GTX 550ti

Edit-Update- I was still having freezing with Xorg Nouveau but I tried changing to Nvidia driver again.This time, after clicking apply changes I left the window open and came back in 15 min. The change to Nvidia worked and seems to have stayed.